# How to set a shortcut to "Customize Keyboard..." in Excel Mac 2011

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, office-for-mac, microsoft-excel-2011

I would like to set a shortcut to "Customize Keyboard..." in Excel Mac 2011 so I could open the "Customize Keyboard" menu via a simple shortcut.

Apparently we can't do do it via Excel because there is no "Customize Keyboard..." file in the "Customize Keyboard..." menu.

I tried setting one up via the System preferences but it does not work too. The shortcut doesn't appear to be assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts*.

Here, create a new Application Shortcut, assign it to *Microsoft Excel.app*, and for the menu entry, type `Customize Keyboard…` (with an ellipsis or three dots at the end.)

It should look like this, and once it's set, you can use your custom shortcut to open the window in Excel:

[image]

Tested on OS X 10.8 with Excel 2011.

Comment: Thanks for putting a screenshot. Made me realize it didn't work because of a typo... Feel so dumb right now. Think my eyes need some rest :-)